# Should i add component or what in enemy unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Well i'm making a rpg and i came across and wondering how does ppl handle the enemys, i know i can instatiate the prefab but by doing it all his childs "scripts,etc" will go with him and for example i have different monsters to read from CSV and add their own stats, meaning that every mob has his own EXP,loot,etc and i'd like to know if its good by code, when loading the monster if i should use the main prefab just to be as the model but add a component script binded to them with different stats or what is the most used way? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most implementations tend to have a prefab for each different enemy with different the correct variables either being predefined in the prefab (or as you want to do) loaded from a CSV file. That said there's nothing wrong with adding the components after instantiating the prefab, that's almost certainly what Unity does internally when you instantiate a prefab. It just may be less convenient than using the prefab and slightly less performant.

If you wanted to minimize the amount of prefabs you had, then you could implement the functionality into an enemy script which would then [load the correct model at runtime](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LoadingResourcesatRuntime.html) and grab the data from the CSV file, but it's not really necessary to do so.

Comment: Thanks alot for the commentary, i was just confused